# Web scraping getting every string after href links

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I'm trying to scrape movie titles in an article in rottentomatoes using beautifulsoup. However, movie titles are after href links of each movie's page. Here's what I'm trying to get:

`<a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_shape_of_water_2017/">The Shape of Water</a>` 
I only want to get the text 'The Shape of Water' I can get this text but this is only for one movie. I want to do this for all movies on the same page, and each movie, the last part of the link changes. Can someone tell me how can I do that, I'm a beginner at web scraping?

Answer (score 0):

```
html_doc = """<a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_shape_of_water_2017/">The Shape of Water</a>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for x in soup:
    print(x.text) # The Shape of Water
```

In beautifulsoap when you want to get the text of the tag just use `text` with the tag

Comment: I edited the question. The last part of the link is the name of the movie, and I was asking how I can get the movie title text for every movie on the same page.

Comment: you don't need to extract from the link when the name of the movie "The Shape of Water" is given in the tag, just get all the links on the site and extract there text

Comment: That doesn't work because not all links are before these texts. There are many links that I don't want.

Comment: then just get the href link and split it on the basics of "/" and get the -2 element in the list

Comment: I tried what you said and `The Broadway Melody
 [More]
Anita Page
Bessie Love
Charles King
Jed Prouty
Harry Beaumont



The Greatest Show on Earth
 [More]
Betty Hutton
Cornel Wilde
Charlton Heston
James Stewart
Cecil B. DeMille
` this is an example part of the outcome. Here it contains each movie and the cast, but I only want the movie title. How can I do that? The movie titles are the texts above '[more]'

Comment: can you share your code it will give me a better idea